# What is the geometry of the intersection of hyperelliptic cones and similar objects?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, polynomials

Given a symmetric matrix $C$ with zeroes on its diagonal I am interested in the solutions of $x^TCx=0$. As $C$ is symmetric with zero trace I can let $C=A^TDA$ for some orthonormal matrix $A$ and diagonal matrix $D$ with at least one positive and negative element (provided $C\neq 0$). If I then make the rotation $y=Ax$ ($A$ is a rotation if you choose the right sign for the eigenvectors) then $x^TCx=0\Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n D_{ii}y_i^2=0$, which is a much easier shape to conceptualise. For example, when $n=3$ it will be an elliptic cone so long as $D_{ii}\neq 0$ for all $i$.

What I am interested in is the intersection of the solutions of $x^TC^kx$ for a collection of matrices $C^1\ldots, C^k$. I can convince myself that the intersection of two unequal elliptic cones is the union of up to four one dimensional subspaces (just look at their mutual intersection on the unit sphere, which are unequal ellipses), but after that I'm lost.

In particular I have two questions. First, what is the name of the shape given by $\sum_{i=1}^na_iy_i^2=0$ where $a_i>0$ for some $i$ and $a_i<0$ for some $i$? Second, if for now we call this shape a hyper-X in n dimensions, is the intersection of two of these shapes a hyper-X in $n-1$-dimensions (outside of some pathological counter-examples)?